# PC stopped booting up with graphics card

Tags: boot, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, motherboard

Its rare but every now and then my computer fails to startup correctly. I press the power button and it starts up. I hear the normal beep as it starts up but then moments later I hear a long beep followed by three short beeps. My computer then restarts and boots up normally.

Just the other day I tried powering on my computer and it did this but this time it kept restarting and doing the beeping thing. One long beep and three short beeps. I am not getting output to my monitors. I removed my graphics card and plugged my monitor into my motherboard and my computer worked fine. When my computer powers up the fans on my graphics card spin.

My question is why is my graphics card doing this and how do I fix it.

Graphics card: Radeon R7 260X
Motherboard: Asus P8H77-V

Comment: http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000996.htm

Answer (score 1):

#### ASUS Beep Codes - 1 Long, 3 Short

[image]
[image]

Source [ASUS Beep Codes](http://support.asus.com/pcassistant/pdf/BeepTable_en-us.pdf)

Comment: Other possible causes , seating of the video card in the slot it is in, proper powering of the video card via the extra power connectors it uses. The PSU failing to deliver enough power, or clean power at that load ammount. Rarer - Cpu lane connections , should there be a very small ammount of pins not properly connecting on the cpu , a motherboard failure. and even ram problems via the gpu ram driver spaces.     All making look fairly easy to just test a different video card first.

Comment: Side note: please do not try shoving your graphics card into the DIMM (memory) slots. You can try the other PCIe slots of the same size.

Answer (score 0):

The graphics card may have been damaged from overheating or from some other unknown cause.  This happens more frequently than you might think.  You could try installing the graphics card in another computer to determine if you can reproduce the problem elsewhere, but the end result will be the same regardless.  You'll have to get a replacement card, which may be covered under warranty.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I do not have another computer to test it in.

Comment: Just vote or mark as a solution if it helped, please.